# Eclipse has bunch of errors when creating an Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to set up my eclipse for android development, I am still a beginner in android app development. I am currently following the book "Android Programming The big nerd ranch guide" As I create a project clicking the "finish" does not do anything but when i closed it the project seems to be there and now when i open it it has a bunch of errors, I kept looking for answers in net but nothing worked here is a screenshot of my eclipse.

I haven't started coding yet.
[image: I haven't started coding yet]

Comment: Google discontinued support for Eclipse 2-3 years ago.

Comment: I would sue whoever suggested you to start developing Android apps with Eclipse...

Comment: Just a question: Is there a special reason for you not to use the official Android IDE and stick with eclipse which is not supported by google anymore?

Comment: The book I'm reading they use eclipse. Oh man, I was stuck fixing these for the entire day.

Comment: So its better if I use android studio instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start using Android Studio, official IDE fro Android Development https://developer.android.com/studio/.

If book is suggesting you Eclipse IDE then probably it's a sign that you should change book as probably you have outdated version.

Book that in my opinion is pretty up to date you can find here
https://commonsware.com/Android/